# How to install gems in rails 2.3.11 from environment.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to install gems in rails 2.3.11 from environment.rb file ?

Below is some of the code of environment.rb file:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem "authlogic", :version => '2.1.3'
  config.gem "paperclip", :version => '2.3.1.1'
  config.gem "geokit", :version => '1.5.0'
  config.gem "will_paginate", :version => '2.3.11'
  config.gem 'easy_roles', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org', :version => '1.0.0'
  config.gem 'fastercsv', :version => '1.5.3'
  config.gem 'chargify_api_ares', :version => '0.3.9'

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `rake gems install`?
This was the way gems were installed in the days before bundler...

Answer (score 0):

install it using

```
rake gems:install
```